# Convert decimal to roman in C - how to return string from function?

Tags: c, string, function, return, decimal

Simple function to convert decimal numbers into roman, but how can i return this string from function? I tried this solution but my program crashes.

```
char roman(int number)
{

char ROMAN[][3] = { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" };

int NUM[] = { 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 }; 

int i;

char buff[100]="\0";

for(i = 0; number > 0 && number < 3999; i++)
  while(number/NUM[i]){
      strcat(buff,ROMAN[i]);
      number -= NUM[i];
  }

return buff;

}
```

In main I got:

```
printf("\nAfter change: %s",roman(decimal_number));
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is declare the buffer in `main`, and pass it to the function. So the function signature is `void roman(int number, char buff[100])`.

Comment: BTW, Think you want `number < 4000`

Answer (score 1):

`buff` is not a single `char`; it is an array of them.  So you'd have to declare the return type of your function accordingly.

But then you have the problem that the string is local to your function; it (conceptually) "goes away" when you return.

Your roughly 2 choices are:

1. Pass `buff` as a parameter.  (In this case, you wouldn't need to return it.)
2. Use dynamic allocation (`malloc`) to allocate the space for `buff`.

Comment: The other choice is to make `buff` a static array.